# How can I change adressfield items order in node display

Tags: entities

I'm using [Address Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield) and [Address Field Phone](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield_phone) modules, the country is dispalyed after the phone number.
[image]
So how I can change the addressfield items order?

Comment: You can simply define node--ContentType.tpl.php

Comment: I tried this, I think the addressfield items are not rendred

Comment: You rendered it in node.tpl or template.tpl ?

Comment: I rendred it in ds template ds-1col-wrapper--node-client.tpl.php, I printed the $content array, addressfield items not found.

Comment: it is node.tpl, see if it is renderable through template.php

Comment: Can u tell me plz how I can render it in template.php, I don't know how to do it. and plz check this comment of ryan szrama https://www.drupal.org/node/1413858#comment-7371466. I posted this question after some resarch.

Comment: in first step you need to `kpr` the parameter of the `hook_preprocess_node` function. look at it's output. the devel module must be installed

Comment: @Drupalist I kpr() the vars inside hook_preprocess_node,the theme was disabled in node view and variables doesn't printed : function garlandsub_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['submitted'] = $vars['date'] . ' — ' . $vars['name'];
  $kpr($vars);
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24599/discussion-between-murad-and-drupalist).